# ggplot sum with conditions

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know there is multiple topics about it but I am new to R, I have been looking for few topics and try them on my data but they don't work and don't understand why.

```
   ID  V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7   Met Pop     Soft    V8 V9
    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   B2  Europe  BWA2    0   0
    2   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   B2  Europe  BWA2    0   0
    3   10  2   0   0   0   0   0   B2  Europe  BWA2    0   2
    4   100 1   0   0   0   0   0   B2  Europe  BWA2    0   1
    ...
    2001001 ZXXH    0   0   0   0   0   0   B2  Europe  BWA2    0   0
    2001002 ZXXP    0   0   0   0   0   0   B2  Europe  BWA2    0   0
    2001003 ZXXV    3   0   0   0   0   0   B2  Europe  BWA2    0   3
    2001004 ZXXZ    1   1   0   0   0   0   B2  Europe  BWA2    0   2
```

In my data V8 is the sum of V5+V6+V7 and V9 the sum of V2+V3+V4.

My goal for now is to represent the amount of value (so the sum) that have V8==0 and for each Soft.
I tried doing so using geom_bar() or geom_histogram() but nothing is showing up on my plots. In   my code I tried using "weights" for the cumulative effects but it doesn't seems to work obviously:

```
ggplot(data=Eur[V8==0], aes(x = Soft, weights = V8)) + 
   geom_bar()
```

Comment: not sure - what do you expect to see for your example? All your `weights` are zero, so it's normal to have all bars of zero height, no?

Comment: I think I found the answer, I wanted to see the amount of IDs with the value of 0 for each software.  I just changed  ggplot(data=Eur[V8==0], aes(x = Soft, weights = V8)) by ggplot(data=Eur, aes(x = Soft, weights = (V8==0)) and it seems to works.. not sure if that's a good way to do it tho'

Comment: it's a good way to do I think